# Unselect or Deselect Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with x worksheets.
And a button (commandbutton1) in Sheet1 which opens a userform with two checkboxes and a Preview Button to choose between 2 sheets to preview in PDF.

Here’s my Preview button code.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim CheckBoxName As String

    For i = 1 To 2
        CheckBoxName = "CheckBox" & i
        If Me.Controls(CheckBoxName).Value = True Then
            Sheets(Me.Controls(CheckBoxName).Caption).Select (False)
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="D:\Preview.pdf"

    Unload Me

    Dim File As String
    File = "D:\Preview.pdf"
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", File, "", "", vbNormalNoFocus
End Sub
```

Now, the problem is that Sheet1 is always included in the preview file since it’s the sheet containing commandbutton1.

So is there a way to deselect sheet1 before exporting sheets 6 & 21 ??

I also tried another way but it always stuck at this line (Sheets(Array(SheetNames)).Select)

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim CheckBoxName As String
    Dim SheetNames As String

    For i = 1 To 2
        CheckBoxName = "CheckBox" & i
        If Me.Controls(CheckBoxName).Value = True Then
            SheetNames = SheetNames & Me.Controls(CheckBoxName).Caption & ","
        End If
    Next i

    SheetNames = Mid(SheetNames, 1, Len(SheetNames) - 1)

    Sheets(Array(SheetNames)).Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="D:\Preview.pdf"

    Unload Me

    Dim File As String
    File = "D:\Preview.pdf"

    ShellExecute 0, "Open", File, "", "", vbNormalNoFocus
End Sub
```

Any help with any of these please ??

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is how you pass the parameter `False` in

```
Sheets(Me.Controls(CheckBoxName).Caption).Select (False)
```

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 1 To 6
        CheckBoxName = "CheckBox" & i
        If Me.Controls(CheckBoxName).Value = True Then
            j = j + 1
            Worksheets(Me.Controls(CheckBoxName).Caption).Select (j = 1)
        End If
    Next
    If j = 0 Then Exit Sub

    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

OR

[image]